# primefaces oneRadio and using inputText as value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to have three radio buttons, the first two have a static value but the third, if checked, the user can type anything into an inputText box. I can get the layout using this code but the form won't submit and I don't get an error anywhere.

```
<p:outputPanel id="customPanel" style="margin-bottom:10px">
    <p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" value="#{backbean.radioselect}" layout="custom">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choice 1" itemValue="choice1" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choice 2" itemValue="choice2" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Custom" itemValue="#{backbean.radioselect != 'choice1' and backbean.radioselect != 'choice2' ? backbean.radioselect : ''}" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:radioButton id="choice1" for="customRadio" itemIndex="0" />
        <h:outputLabel for="choice1" value="Choice 1" />

        <p:radioButton id="choice2" for="customRadio" itemIndex="1" />
        <h:outputLabel for="choice2" value="Choice 2" />

        <p:radioButton id="choiceCustom" for="customRadio" itemIndex="2" />
        <p:inputText style="width: 100%;" value="#{backbean.radioselect != 'choice1' and backbean.radioselect != 'choice2' ? backbean.radioselect : ''}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: why is value of selectOneRadio and inputText the same - #{backbean.radioselect} ?

Comment: That was for if it didn't equal choice1 or choice2, it would be the custom one which then I would pre-populate the inputText to what the value was from before if there was one. @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar

Comment: If the EL expression of an inputText is computed and a setter cannot be called then the form cannot be submitted --> value="#{backbean.radioselect != 'choice1' and backbean.radioselect != 'choice2' ? backbean.radioselect : ''} . Please add  <p:ajax update="customPanel" process="@this myGrid" listener="#{backBean.doLogic}"/>. and do you business logic there instead of EL. add id="myGrid" in your panelGrid.

Comment: I have a commandButton later than updates the form, my problem is when I add this block of code to the form, it no longer reaches the backing bean. Removing this code everything works the way I think it should. @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar

Comment: Yes it wont work unfortunately. JSF requires **input** components to have EL expressions like #{backbean.myInput} so that the setters can be called. So please change the EL in inputText and redesign.

Comment: @Kukeltje he is using custom layout only. rendering works for him but form submission doesnt due to EL expression of inputText value="#{backbean.radioselect != 'choice1' and backbean.radioselect != 'choice2' ? backbean.radioselect : ''}"

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar ooooops removed comment! Tnx. No idea why I thought it was a home-grown trial... Maybe to little sleep